# serial port how do I?

Tags: java

Hi I am using Netbeans as my IDE. I want to play a little bit with the serial port. I am using an FTDI cable in my laptop that converts usb port to RS232 serial port.

I have found these interesting sites:
http://www.embeddedunveiled.com/
https://github.com/RishiGupta12/serial-communication-manager

I have written this piece of code taken from first link
under
Example usage
•How to find serial ports available on system is here.

code:

```
package findserialports;

import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */

public class FindSerialPorts {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SerialComManager scm = new SerialComManager();
            String[] ports = scm.listAvailableComPorts();
            for(String port: ports){
                System.out.println(port);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

There is an error in code in statement
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager;

Also it says on site second link
that The folder prebuilt contains ready-to-use jar file (scm-1.0.3.jar) that can be imported in any project and referenced right away.
Where do I find the prebuild folder?

thanks

----------Second Post----------------------------------------------

Moving on I have following code:

```
package serialportftdi;

import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.BAUDRATE;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.DATABITS;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.FLOWCONTROL;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.PARITY;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.STOPBITS;


/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */
public class SerialPortFTDI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SerialComManager scm = new SerialComManager();
            long handle = scm.openComPort("/dev/ttyUSB1", true, true, false);               scm.configureComPortData(handle, DATABITS.DB_8, STOPBITS.SB_1, PARITY.P_NONE, BAUDRATE.B115200, 0);
            scm.configureComPortControl(handle, FLOWCONTROL.NONE, 'x', 'x', false, false);
            scm.writeString(handle, "testing hello", 0) == true);
            String data = scm.readString(handle);
            System.out.println("data read is :" + data);
            scm.closeComPort(handle);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

An error occurs at line : `scm.writeString(handle, "testing hello", 0) == true);`

```
C:\Users\Alexandros\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SerialPortFTDI\src\serialportftdi\SerialPortFTDI.java:31: error: not a statement
            scm.writeString(handle, "testing hello", 0) == true);
                                                        ^
C:\Users\Alexandros\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SerialPortFTDI\src\serialportftdi\SerialPortFTDI.java:31: error: ';' expected
            scm.writeString(handle, "testing hello", 0) == true);
                                                               ^
2 errors
C:\Users\Alexandros\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SerialPortFTDI\nbproject\build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Alexandros\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SerialPortFTDI\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Also I am trying to understand the code but I don't understand what 'handle' does. Is this a *handle* as in C++? If yes then what exactly does? I was trying to find info about it in Java Deitel and wrox books but no info.

Comment: No handle is a number. If you look carefully in your code second statement in your try block.  long handle = scm.openComPort("/dev/ttyCOM4", true, true, false); here handle is a long number returned by scm.openComPort method.

Comment: Also please post stack trace of the error

Comment: I have looked at the docs and found that scm.openComPort returns the handle of opened port. And if you try to open an already opened port then an exception is thrown. See javadocs here http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.embeddedunveiled/scm/1.0.3

Comment: Yes I have read doc. So question 1: What is a handle in Java

Comment: Yes I have read doc. So  Q.1: What is a handle in Java? Q.2: the first argument of method openComPort() "/dev/ttyUSB1" should be changed to "COM4" or "/dev/ttyCOM4" ?     Q.3. the 4th argument of openComPort() should be true for windows .      Have a look on the errors edited in post.

Comment: Handle is reference to method or another reference. http://www.rajeshpatkar.com/articles/javarefpnt/ provides more detail about handles. For windows it should be "CON:COM4" instead of "dev/ttry/COM4" but I am not sure try googling it. Keeping fourth argument true is good.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I played a little bit with code and now it works fine. Bare in mind that the ftdi cable must be inserted to the usb port that is found as being connected to COM4 serial port.

Code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package serialportftdi;

import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.BAUDRATE;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.DATABITS;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.FLOWCONTROL;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.PARITY;
import com.embeddedunveiled.serial.SerialComManager.STOPBITS;


/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */
public class SerialPortFTDI {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SerialComManager scm = new SerialComManager();
            long handle = scm.openComPort("COM4", true, true, true);
            scm.configureComPortData(handle, DATABITS.DB_8, STOPBITS.SB_1, PARITY.P_NONE, BAUDRATE.B115200, 0);
            scm.configureComPortControl(handle, FLOWCONTROL.NONE, 'x', 'x', false, false);
            scm.writeString(handle, "testing hello", 0); //== true);
            String data = scm.readString(handle);
            System.out.println("data read is :" + data);
            scm.closeComPort(handle);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You got it right. The only error left was this syntactical error.